# Date and Time Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, date, time, formatting

I have dates with times listed and would like to perform conditional formating to color the times that do not match 3:00 AM.  I cannot figure it out.

For example:

```
10/2/17 12:00 AM
10/2/17 3:00 AM
10/3/17 10:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following formula (replacing `A1` with your specific cell) into the conditional formatting formula bar:

```
= NOT(AND(HOUR(A1)=3,MINUTE(A1)=0))
```

Comment: Great! If this answer works, you should mark it as the accepted answer by placing a checkmark next to it.

Answer (score -1):

For conditional formatting in Excel, go to this option on the Home menu. And, select the option New Rule.

*Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Format All Cells Based on Their Values*

If your date and time both are in a same cell then you have to create a formula in the formatting condition to convert the date/time value into a string value and will need to extract the time portion out of it to apply value based formatting on it.